# Using external modules with statically linked lua

Tags: lua, static-linking

Recently, I've purchased a game that uses lua for modding support. Unfortunately, lua has been statically linked and there are no dll's at all. It appears to be running lua 5.2 and I don't think any of the lua functions have been modified. I don't have access to the source but debugging info was included with the executable. I'm attempting to use an external library (luasockets) which seems to come with it's own version of lua (lua5.1.dll). Loading the library causes the game to immediately crash without a useful stacktrace. any way to make this work short of rewriting all the lua functions in the exe?